# SMTP: Failed to connect socket: Connection Refused

Tags: php, email, smtp, pear

I'm trying to send an email in PHP using PEAR Mail package and SMTP, but I keep getting the error `SMTP: Failed to connect socket: Connection Refused`

I don't really know anything about how SMTP works, so bear with me.

**Here is my code:**

```
$recipients = $_SESSION['email'];
$headers["From"] = "example@example.com";
$headers["To"] = "example@example.com";
$headers["Subject"] = 'Subject Text!';
$mailmsg = $_SESSION['body'];

/* SMTP server name, port, user/password */
$smtpinfo["host"] = "mail.example.com";
$smtpinfo["port"] = "587";
$smtpinfo["auth"] = true;
$smtpinfo["username"] = $email_user;
$smtpinfo["password"] = $email_pass;
/* Create the mail object using the Mail::factory method */
$mail_object =& Mail::factory("smtp", $smtpinfo);
/* Ok send mail */
$send = $mail_object->send($recipients, $headers, $mailmsg);
if (PEAR::isError($send)) {
    echo '<p>Error: ' . $send->getMessage() . '</p>';
} else {
    header('Location: ../../emailed.php');
}
```

**What I know is:**

Domain is hostgator, and the email handler is Keiro Connect.

I'm not sure which port to go through. I looked at the services, and it says that the Listening IP Addresses are:

- SMTP: All addresses:25, All addresses:587
- Secure SMTP: All addresses:465
- SMTP Submission: All addresses:587 **this service is turned off though*

I've also noted that SMTP delivery is set to deliver directly using DNS MX records. I don't know if that means anything.

What am I doing wrong? What should I be looking for so I can get all the parameters in order?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is more of a server issue than a coding issue. The remote host is preventing the connection. Might be better served by ServerFault

Answer (score 5):

Just because you are listening on a port doesn't mean you can access it. A firewall either on the system or an upstream inline device could be block it.

From you local machine that you are running the script from, do `telnet mail.example.com 587` and are you brought to a prompt?

Comment: The prompt is:  Trying: XXX.XX.X.XXX...    Connected to waiter.example.com.    Escape character is '^]'.    220 waiter.example.com Kerio Connect 7.4.1 ESMTP ready

Comment: Ok, great! That means that you are able to establish a connection to the server. Next, does `$email_user` include the @domain.com?

Comment: No, just the username before @domain.com

Answer (score 0):

I have faced such issue before.. And eaten up my hours to resolve...
**Try your script on server also**.. Some times **for some SMTP hosts, You can not send emails from local machine**.
I am adding answer(or suggestion) too late.. But It may help someone..

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have an ssl certification I suggest using port 25. After I get an ssl I will be changing port configurations to 465. Why are you using that port number? I don't think it is in compliance with hostgator.
Check out this webpage from hostgator. http://support.hostgator.com/articles/email-connection-settings